# How to move MDIcon to the right of the left edge?

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivymd

I'm designing a header for a page of my app using kivy. Here is what it currently looks like:
[image]

Here is what I want it to look like:
[image]

Here's my code:

```
<FlatButton@ButtonBehavior+Label>:
    font_size: 14

<TransactionWindow>:
    id: main_win
    orientation: 'vertical'
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: (1,1,1, 1)
        Rectangle:
            size: self.size
            pos: self.pos

    BoxLayout:
        id: header
        size_hint_y: None
        height: 104
        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgba: (186/255, 215/255, 233/255, 1)
            Rectangle:
                size: self.size
                pos: self.pos
        padding_left: 0.4567
        MDIcon:
            icon: 'arrow-left'
            width: sp(34.67)
            height: sp(34.67)
            font_size: sp(69)
            pos_hint: {'right': 0.9145,'top': 0.8333}

        Label:
            text: 'Checkout Counter > New Order'
            font: 'Lexend-Regular'
            font_size: sp(45)
            size_hint_x: .9
            bold: False
            color: (43/255,52/255,103/255,1)
```

I tried to modify MDIcon pos_hint but nothing happened. What should I do so that the distance from the arrow to the left edge and to the label is euqal to 45.67 pixels?